# How to change the background color of a button with askcolor

Tags: python, tkinter

I am pretty new to python but im just trying to change the color of the bg of a button i have been trying to do it on my own for a while but i am not getting any where.

all the code for a example

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import colorchooser
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x100")
window.title("test")
notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(window)

v69 = IntVar()



def teste():
    colors = colorchooser.askcolor()
    Button.configure(window, )


Button(window,text="test button",command =teste,  bg="white").grid(row=1,column=0)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ya have there is a [catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)).  You need the **Button defined** in order to configure its *background*.  However, you need the *background function defined*, in order to pass that as a callback **for the button**...

So what you have to do is, essentially create an empty button without any callback yet, a [forward-declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration), then use `.configure()` to add your callback in.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import colorchooser
from tkinter .colorchooser import askcolor

window = Tk()
window .geometry( '200x100' )
window .title( 'test' )

notebook = ttk .Notebook( window )
tabControl = ttk .Notebook( window )

color = Button( window, text='test button', bg='white' )  ##  empty button

def test():  ##  now has a color button to .configure()
    colors = colorchooser .askcolor()
    ##  returns both RGB and HEX values   ( {255 255 255}, #ffffff )
    color .configure( bg=colors[1] )  ##  so grab the rightmost element [1]

color .configure( command=test )  ##  complete callback
color .grid( row=1, column=0 )

window .mainloop()
```